# HTML form does not submit with file upload

Tags: html, file-upload

EDIT: This seems to be due to the file itself and possibly where it is stored on the machine (it's on a mounted volume). It is unlikely to be related to the form or Django, since other files work as expected.

I have a pretty simple HTML page with a form which is behaving very strangely:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">

  <title>Add picture</title>
</head>

<body class="app-products model-picture change-form">
  <!-- Container -->

  <div id="container">
    <!-- Header -->

    <div id="header">
      <div id="branding">
        <h1 id="site-name">administration</h1>
      </div>
    </div><!-- END Header -->
    <!-- Content -->

    <div id="content" class="colM">
      <h1>Add picture</h1>

      <div id="content-main">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=
        "/admin/products/picture/add/" method="post" id="picture_form"
        novalidate="" name="picture_form">
          <div>
            <fieldset class="module aligned">
              <div class="form-row field-alt_text">
                <div>
                  <label class="required" for="id_alt_text">Alt text:</label>
                  <textarea class="vLargeTextField" cols="40" id="id_alt_text"
                  name="alt_text" rows="10">
</textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row field-original_image">
                <div>
                  <label class="required" for="id_original_image">Original
                  image:</label> <input id="id_original_image" name=
                  "original_image" type="file">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="submit-row">
              <input type="submit" value="Save" class="default" name="_save">
              <input type="submit" value="Save and add another" name=
              "_addanother"> <input type="submit" value=
              "Save and continue editing" name="_continue">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div><br class="clear">
    </div><!-- END Content -->

    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div><!-- END Container -->
</body>
</html>
```

It is being served up by a django application as a static file (to keep things simple).

When I click the "Save" button to submit the form without filling it out at all (or if I put some text in the `textarea`), I see a `POST` request go through to the django application as expected. However, if I choose a file with the "file" input and then try to submit the form, no `POST` request reaches the application. In fact, no request is sent (I'm watching the HTTP traffic in wireshark). In Google chrome, I see the following error page:

[image: Google chrome error page]

Any ideas?

Comment: How does you urls/view look like?

Comment: That isn't relevant. The form submission works as expected unless a specific file is selected for upload. A request never reaches the django application.

Comment: It's nice that you provided the HTML, but the issue is obviously on the backend or client side.

Comment: As a wild guess since you don't provide any more info... can you end your url path in (r'^/admin/products/picture/add/?$') so that the trailing slash is optional?

Comment: I think this question is too specific to my situation to be answered here on Stackoverflow. It has something to do with the files and/or media volume that I'm attempting to access the file to upload from. It has nothing to do with django. I have voted to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are the name of your inputs separated by a white space?
`name= "myinputname"`

If so, the form will not process.

Comment: The HTML is valid according to the W3C validator. I tried it without the whitespace and still experienced the same problems.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Spaces are valid name characters, and validate in the W3C Validator.